# Get the string return by \namecref to use in another command

Tags: expansion

Suppose I have a theorem with `\label{thm}`, and I want to create a theorem of the same type as thm, here's what I want it ideally behaves:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}


\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm}
    \lipsum[1][1-2]
\end{theorem}

% Want to create a theorem of the same type
\begin{\namecref{thm}}
    \lipsum[1][3-4]
\end{\namecref{thm}}

% Ideally it would be like this:
\begin{theorem}
    \lipsum[1][3-4]
\end{theorem}


\end{document}
```

But this leads to errors `Missing \endcsname` and `Environment \namecref{thm} undefined`. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\namecref` is not expandable and can't be used as a string (and even if it could: at the first compilation you could get an error if you don't provide a fallback).

You could store the environment in another label with a property. This requires a current LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
\NewProperty{currenvir}{now}{unknown}{\@currenvir}
\makeatother
\newenvironment{unknown}{\textbf{UNKNOWN ENV}}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm}\RecordProperties{envthm}{currenvir}
    \lipsum[1][1-2]
\end{theorem}

% Want to create a theorem of the same type
\begin{\RefProperty{envthm}{currenvir}}
    \lipsum[1][3-4]
\end{\RefProperty{envthm}{currenvir}}

% Ideally it would be like this:
\begin{theorem}
    \lipsum[1][3-4]
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can one use these new commands in `ltproperty` to create `minitoc` without a package? What are the current thoughts with `hyperref` integration?

Answer (score 5):

You need to extract the name from the annotation `cleveref` does in the aux file.

Note that `\namecref` will *not* return `theorem`, but “Theorem”.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{??????}{??????} % for when a ref is undefined

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{reftheorem}[1]{%
  \ifcsname r@#1@cref\endcsname
    \edef\reftheorem@type{\reftheorem@extract{#1}}%
  \else
    \def\reftheorem@type{??????}%
  \fi
  \begin{\reftheorem@type}%
}{\end{\reftheorem@type}}

\newcommand\reftheorem@extract[1]{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\reftheorem@@extract
  \csname r@#1@cref\endcsname
}
\newcommand\reftheorem@@extract[2]{\reftheorem@@@extract#1\@nil}
\def\reftheorem@@@extract[#1]#2\@nil{#1}
\makeatother


\begin{document}


\begin{theorem}\label{thm}
    \lipsum[1][1-2]
\end{theorem}

\begin{reftheorem}{thm}
    \lipsum[1][3-4]
\end{reftheorem}

% Ideally it would be like this:
\begin{theorem}
    \lipsum[1][3-4]
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

At the first run you'd get “?????? 1”.

[image]

Comment: +1 for the elegant solution that doesn't require altering the original theorem, making it particularly convenient for integrating into macros. I've chosen to accept @Ulrike Fischer's answer due to its informative approach using the new `ltproperties`.